# Find all last children from a table

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

```
idTask  idParent  Description
1                 Root  
2          1      Parent-1
3          1      Parent-2
4          1      Parent-3
5          1      Parent-4
6          4      Child31   
7          4      Child32   
8          5      Child41   
9          8      Child411
10         8      Child412
```

I need a query to retrieve the records like,

**Output**

```
2          1      Parent-1
3          1      Parent-2
6          4      Child31   
7          4      Child32   
9          8      Child411
10         8      Child412
```

Comment: i don't know what a 'last child' is.

Comment: I think he means leaves in the tree, nodes with no children?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein Yes.

Comment: @RahulS. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean leaves in the tree, you can just look for rows without children by self-joining the table and look for NULL records:

```
SELECT parent.Id 
FROM task parent LEFT OUTER JOIN task child on child.idParent= parent.IdTask
WHERE child.IdTask IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from task t1 where not exists (select 1 from task where idParent = t1.idTask)
```

Comment: Indent by 4 spaces to present your code in a monospace font.. Personally I'd go the left join route, as I try to keep to the "do not use IN for lists longer than you'd be prepared to write by hand" rule of thumb, but it should work! :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Agree with you, EXISTS is more preferable option over IN